# How to build pure functions in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, functional-programming

In my role at work I use AngularJS (1.x) and Node. For reasons beyond me, we don't use ui-router. Thus we have to maintain a lot of view state in controller variables. The cleanest solution I've been able to design is using a "$scope.view" variable which is responsible for all view logic within the controller. For example:

```
$scope.view = {
            loading: true,
            loadMoreBtn: {
                state: '',
                // TODO - Is this pure? Could it be?
                shouldHide: function(data) {
                    return data.length === 0 || data.length === $scope.dataInScope.length;
                },
                setState: function(state) {
                    this.state = state;
                },
                getNgClass: function() {
                    return this.state;
                }
            }
        };
```

Ex. Since $scope is the same when accessed directly vs. passed-in, is it considered impure to access it directly? Is there a more-pure way to do this?

```
shouldHide: function(data) {
    return data.length === 0 || data.length === $scope.dataInScope.length;
},
```

I've searched "functional angularjs" and read a few articles. But I'm still having difficulty seeing how and where to apply functional programming within Angular.

Is this the correct approach to managing view state without ui-router? Am I stark-raving mad? How might more experienced developers tackle this issue in a more functional manner?

Comment: Not clear what your issue really is or what higher level problem you are trying to solve. Sounds like what you really need is a service

Comment: @charlietfl I'm looking for clarification on 1. whether my method is pure form a functional standpoint considering what I mentioned about $scope and 2. is this the proper way to handle view state without ui-router?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"$scope is the same when accessed directly vs. passed-in"*. ALso if you need to duplicate this in a number of controllers the methods should be put in a service and keep the controllers lean

Comment: @charlietfl So a pure function cannot rely on a variable that exists outside of itself. It must be passed in via a parameter. My question is: If calling `view.shouldHide(dataObj)` is the same as calling `$scope.dataObj` _inside_ the `view.shouldHide` function, then are they essentially the same? Can a pure function reference $scope?

Comment: sure it can.... Lots of time things get passed in from the view that then need to  manipulate or be compared to scope

Comment: And functions that do that can still be considered "pure" in the context of functional programming?

Comment: Not even sure what you mean by *"pure"*

Comment: A "pure" function is a function that does is referentially transparent, and does not create side-effects. I'm mostly unconcerned about the side-effects because I don't know if I can do that with AngularJS. But what I'm concerned with is whether or not $scope could be considered referentially transparent without being passed in.